# Is there a way to take bigger resolution screenshots via retroarch rgui option?

Tags: retropie, screenshot

I am running retropie 4.x.x the latest version.

When taking a screenshot during a game via the rgui it saves the screenshot with a resolution of 853*480.

Is there a way to get retroarch to save them at a better resolution.

I have changed the video settings in retroarch to make the game look better.

but the screenshot is not taken at the size displayed on the screen and when used as splashscreen it is blown up and distorted unlike when the game is played.

any information or links into the right direction would be much appreciated.

I tried googling but all the links i found are for enabling retroarch screenshot or for getting rgui screenshots and not about screenshot configuration.

I am hoping it is just a screenshot configuration/setting I can change via nano or something.

one thing that might work but would mean using a keyboard or random controller key combo to work is to use raspi2png but apparently the built retroarch screen capture is better. I have yet to test raspi2png as I have a good setup at the moment of retropie and not much space for a full SD card backup on my laptop to be able to test raspi2png without a backup in case i break my retropie.

All help much appreciated and thankyou for taking the time to read my question.

kind regards and have a pleasant day.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot size via the RGUI of retroarch is all dependent on the video output mode selected for the specific emulator.

the bigger the output video mode the bigger the screenshot size.

hope this helps everyone.

ps yes I edited my own answer as I was wrong.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.